# Regex Pattern for password field

Tags: java

I have a password field where I want to have atleast one special character, atleast one uppercase character and atleast one numeric digit. Can anyone help me with the regex pattern please.

Thank You

Comment: I dont understand why this question has been upvoted! I cant see any effort from the OP's side.

Comment: Do you really want to enforce this? People will just add an uppercase at the start, and a 1$ at the end. Not sure enforcing this actually increases security. Password1$ isn't any more secure than password.

Answer (score 4):

```
Pattern pwPattern = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[@#$!\"&])(?=.*[A-Z]).*\\d.*");
```

Add more special characters inside the first brackets if you want to allow more, I just added a few.

Use it like this:

```
if (pwPattern.matcher(passWordToTest).matches()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this have to end in a digit?

Comment: +1 But for me it also works without `.*` at the end even when the pw does not end with a digit.

Comment: @FabianBarney: Not in Java when using `.matches()`.

Comment: @user1530678: If you want to insert `^` into the character class, do it at the end of the class; if you insert `-`, do it at the start. Otherwise they change the meaning of what's in the class.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ah ok, I used `.find()` in my test.

Comment: @user1530678: Should it show error? You only said that it was required that it contains at least one uppercase character.

Comment: @Keppil: It even accepts the password even if i do not enter an Uppercase character.Thanks